# Blazor not providing individual sessions. How to fix?

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have a Blazor Server app hosted on an Azure App Service, which communicates to an on-premises server connected through a VNET on Azure.

I have custom authentication in place where a user will use their login credentials which is validated in the on-premises server which returns a token.

---

Now my issue is that it seems like there aren't individual instances of the app.
I've come to this conclusion because of the following scenario I've encountered:

I have a ZXing barcode scanner which displays a decoded barcode in the following manner:

```
<input type='text' value='@Barcode' disabled="disabled" />
```

The value is displayed in the textbox once a barcode is found.

Here is my issue:

1. Open the app using live URL on my **mobile phone** and on my **PC**
2. I scan the code on my phone
3. The PC's textbox is updated with the code I just scanned on my phone?

Is there a specific configuration I'm missing or am I misunderstanding how Blazor works?

Comment: Can you share a little more code? Where does @Barcode come from? Depending on how you set things up, some things are shared between sessions (for example by registering a service with AddSingleton()).

Comment: Repeat the same trick once more, and then type your app's url in a new tab or a different browser. What do you see ? You're supposed to see a new instance of your app, even if you open it in a new tab. Authenticate as another user

Comment: So what your saying is that two separate sessions display the data input in one of the sessions.  This can only happen if the data is either stored in a permanent data store, a static class or in a singleton service, and there's an event driven mechanisms to update values in components.

Comment: I finally found the cause. It turns out that the [ZXing Blazor barcode scanner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/) was causing this issue. I manually integrated the [JS library](https://github.com/zxing-js/library) and all is working as intended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause was the [BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS, Blazor barcode scanner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/) .

I manually implemented the [JS library](https://github.com/zxing-js/library) and my problem disappeared.